# Firebase realtime database 64MB/minute write limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the documentation, firebase realtime database has 64MB/minute write limit. My questions is it database writes operate size limit that all online users can write 64 MB data to realtime database in one minute. And if user want to write more than 64 MB/minute data. Also, what if user write 64/MB data is 10 sec than other 50 sec data will be discord.

Comment: May I ask: where did you find this 64MB/minute write limit?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes: Limit is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes)

Comment: Thank you very much qbix ;) @BobSnyder

Answer (score 1):

[All limits are per database for all writes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/UFJH27BRMu8), not per user.  Other writes beyond this limit will be blocked until the bandwidth allows.

Comment: thanks #Doug .If I send 100 MB data will firebase going to handled that 64 mb in min  and than 36 mb in next minute. Or I have to handled that 100 MB write.

Comment: The write will finish when it finishes.  Other writes may be waiting for it to finish if it's not able to finish within the stated bandwidth.